# "not an instance of a persistable class" SDN 4.1.6

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I'm new to Java, Neo4j and Spring Data and I'm experiencing some difficulties with the latter.

I'm currently using Spring Data Neo4j 4.1.6. and I have a basic class Person, which is marked with @NodeEntity. It has no-argument constructor and one constructor with String name just for tests.

After a lot of errors I managed to get to the point, where I have a Neo4jTemplate. **THE PROBLEM** is that when I try to save the Objects of the class Person in the database I get a warning that these are not instances of a persistable class.

e.g. *WARN org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession - Thread 1:xtractor.Person is not an instance of a persistable class*

Here is my **Configuration class** and **Thanks in advance**.

```
package xtractor;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.template.Neo4jOperations;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.template.Neo4jTemplate;


@Configuration
public class Neo4jConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration{

    @Bean
    public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration getConfiguration() {

        org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration config = 
        new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration();
        config.driverConfiguration().
setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver")
        .setURI("file:///" + Console.dbLocation + ".db");

        return config;
    }


    @Override
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        // with domain entity base package(s)
        return new SessionFactory(getConfiguration(), "xtractor.*");//tried everything here
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return Console.db; //thats the DatabaseService I use. 
    }

    @Bean
    //@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public Session getSession() throws Exception{
        return super.getSession();
    }



    @Bean
    public Neo4jOperations neo4jTemplate() throws Exception{
        return new Neo4jTemplate(getSession());
    }

}
```

**Edit: Person.class**
I think the problem is that I can't make Neo4j scan for these @NodeEntities

```
package xtractor;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.*;

@NodeEntity
public class Person {


    @GraphId
    private Long graphId;


    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;


    private int birthdate;
    private String birthplace;

    public Person(){

    }
    public Person(String firstName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        System.out.println("Person created");
    }



    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Show your `Person` class and any other class that refers to it (e.g. has it as a field)

Comment: @frant.hartm 
Currently these are the only classes that exist, together with Console.class
where I just create the db and 3 Person Instances and try to save them using a Neo4jTemplate. 
If you could tell me, how does Neo4j scan for NodeEntities, it would be of great help.

Comment: Ok, that looks fine. The SessionFactory takes packages, not patterns so try just `xtractor` (without `.*`). Also could you post whole sample e.g. on github? It would make it much easier to help...

Comment: I tried all kinds of combinations there. When I put "xtractor" there, I get an org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ServiceNotFoundException:  Resource: rsrc: xtractor/. 

I will post it, just have to sign up.

Comment: Here is the project in Github
https://github.com/blablabla121/xtractor-repo

Comment: I was able to run your project and it works fine (I had to remove `newEmbeddedDatabase` creating -that is done by ogm), only when I change `xtractor` to something else it shows the warning.